# Sphinx sort problem?

Tags: sphinx

i am using 1.10 sphinx.

```
source tags
{
    type                            = mysql
    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = abc
    sql_pass                        = 123456
    sql_db                          = company
    sql_sock                        =  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    sql_port                        = 3306

     sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
     sql_query_range        = SELECT 1,max(id) FROM companies

sql_query                       = \
        SELECT id,name FROM companies;
;
      sql_attr_str2ordinal = name  

}
```

this is sorted by name but i am retriving data.
the result set is `[name] => 954 ......` like this coming .

`sql_attr_str2ordinal = name`  before use this i am using `sql_field_string = name that name` is retrive but not sort by name.
what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

[sql_attr_str2ordinal](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-str2ordinal) :

Does not stores the value only stores the sort order (ordinal) after indexing. so you can not the value from it.

[sql_field_string](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-field-string) :

full-text field but lacks sorting (since its not an attribute).

[sql_attr_string](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-string) :

lacks full-text index.

So what I would do is :

```
source tags
{
    type                            = mysql
    sql_host                        = localhost
    sql_user                        = abc
    sql_pass                        = 123456
    sql_db                          = company
    sql_sock                        =  /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    sql_port                        = 3306

     sql_query_pre = SET NAMES utf8
     sql_query_range        = SELECT 1,max(id) FROM companies

     sql_query                       = \
        SELECT id,name as name_ordinal, name as name FROM companies;
     sql_attr_str2ordinal = name_ordinal
     sql_field_string = name


}
```

Then sort by **name_ordinal** and query with **name**

Comment: you can mean "sql_attr_str2ordinal" replace with sql_attr_string.it will be return sorting by name and return the value.

Comment: I fixed my answer since there was a mistake in it

Comment: ok thanku . i need help on real time indexes with one example.thank u for ur fast replay.

Comment: for realtime indexes I used delta method having 2 indexes (1 big, 1 having the differences). Query on both indexes, update delta index every x minutes. every x hours or days I merge indexes.

Comment: I guess this would help you better : 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/delta-updates.html

Comment: you can comment on real-updates in the other question you asked. So we would help others who stucked at the same question aswell